# gRPC Error : io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: io.grpc.Context was cancelled without error

Tags: java, runtime-error, grpc, grpc-java

Getting the "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: io.grpc.Context was cancelled without error" error in java. using newBlockingStub and while calling stub.method() this error is occurred.

Need to make the successful grpc call

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the stub being called on a server when servicing an incoming RPC?